# SSRS date range parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report in SSRS 2016 that contains one SP which has a date field called startdate.  I'd like to create a parameter where the user can select between two ranges: startdate >='2017'or startdate < '2017'.  This seems like it should be simple, but I can't see to find an easy way to do this.

I've tried to create a parameter in SSRS where I chose "Specify Values" and manually added these values but I get an error that the "expression references the parameter "startdate" which does not exist in the Parameters collection.

I'm sure I can create this by creating a stored procedure with these dates, but that seems like more work than is needed.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by *the user can select between two ranges: startdate >='2017-01-01' or startdate < '2017-01-01'.* Are you wanting the user to choose two dates for the report, and filter the results where the start date is between the two? A query containing `WHERE startdate >= '20170101' AND startdate < '20170101'` would return no results, as something cannot be greater or equal to a value while being less than the same value.

Comment: I want the user to have two options to choose from: startdate>='2017' would be the first option.  The second option would be startdate < '2017'.

Comment: What if you allow the user to select these ranges and pass a varchar instead of a date/datetime field? i.e. The drop down would offer two options 'Before' or 'After' and you could filter within the sproc based off of these values? That seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Add 2 parameters to your SSRS report, for example called `DtStart` and `DtEnd`. Then, in your where clause, use `AND StartDate >= @DtStart AND StartDate < @dtEnd`.

Comment: @Steliok--can you be more specific on how to filter within the sproc based on the values?  Right now my SPROC looks like: and Datefrom >='2015-01-01'.

Comment: @Larnu--if I try this the parameters populate with every date.  I just want the selection to be "Before 2017" and "Since 2017"

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have a parameter that has two options, 0 - Before 2017, and 1 - After 2017 then you should just create a Date parameter which has two options, Before 1/1/2017 in the label field with a 0 in the value field and After 1/1/17 in the label field with a 1 in the value field. Then in your report you just have to filter your data based upon the 1 or 0 value.

For example:

```
DECLARE @DateFilter INT = 1

    IF ( @DateFilter = 0 )
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable t
            WHERE t.DateFilter < '1/1/17'
        END

    IF ( @DateFilter = 1 )
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable t
            WHERE t.DateFilter >='1/1/17' 
        END
```

I don't know why you would filter your data this way. I recommend to use Larnu's suggestion that you have two parameters, a Start Date and an End Date. Otherwise this could return a lot of rows for the second option as time goes on.

Comment: @Jesalyn--this is what I'm looking for, but I'm confused as to how to implement this. I created a new dataset in SSRS called DateFilter and used that code.  I then created a parameter called DateFilter and used Before as a Label with a value = 0, and After as a label with a value = 1.  I get the same results for both selections.

Comment: Make sure your query or stored procedure uses this filter. I used separate if statements so it would filter differently on these values. Can you post your code that you are using the parameters for?

Comment: I ended up creating one dataset with dates before 2017 and another with dates after 2017.  The dropdown box runs one report if the before is selected and the other if the after is selected.  It's probably not the most efficient way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add a couple of parameters in SSRS say, FromDate and ToDate and make its data type as Date/Time.
You can specify the default values for these parameters using DateAdd functions and samples give below:

Today:

```
=Today()
```

last week from today:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7,Today())
```

You can add/reduce year, quarter month etc. in a similar way as shown below. Just change the number to the required length

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Quarter,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.DayOfYear,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekDay,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Second,-1,Today())
```